# PHP: DOM get the count of <xxx/> within <li> element

Tags: php, dom

How do I check to see if the '`li`' element has a '`star`' element inside it, and also get the count of the star elements?

```
<random>
  <li>
      Blah blah <star item="1"/> blah <star item="2"/> Blah blah blah
  </li>
  <li>
      Blah blah Blah blah blah
  </li>
</random>
```

I'm currently using the following code to select one 'li' element (`$liToProcess`) at random. The 'star' check should happen after one li is selected.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($ul);

        $liElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
        $liCount = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;
        // Select a random li
        $useThisItem = rand(0, $liCount-1);
        $liToProcess = $liElements->item($useThisItem)->nodeValue;
        // This echo will output 'Blah blah blah Blah blah blah' (if first li is selected)
        echo "li: " . $liToProcess;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($ul);

    $liElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
    $liCount = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;
    // Select a random li
    $useThisItem = rand(0, $liCount-1);

    $liToProcess = $liElements->item($useThisItem)->nodeValue;
    // This echo will output 'Blah blah blah Blah blah blah' (if first li is selected)
    echo $liElements->item($useThisItem)->childNodes->length . "<br>";
    $noStars = 0;
        if($liElements->item($useThisItem)->childNodes->length > 1) {

           foreach($liElements->item($useThisItem)->childNodes as $cN) {
               if(isset($cN->tagName) && ($cN->tagName === "star") ){
                   // echo $cN->tagName . "<br/>"; 
                   $noStars++;
               }
           }   
        }        


    echo "li: " . $liToProcess . "<br/>\n";
    echo "No of Stars = $noStars <br/>\n";
```